# How to drop ssh session in shell? ssh keeps session alive even after script exits

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

How to drop ssh session in an automation script write in bash?
I have a script running local to trigger a script on a remote machine, and the script on remote machine will trigger another script running in the background...
I want to drop the session while keep the remote machine still running the background script, so I use nohup.

I have a local script `localScript` as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "start remote trigger script..."
./trigger
```

the `trigger` script is ready on my remote machine with the following lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "start script test..."
nohup ./test > output &
echo "start test script in background, exit..."
exit
```

The `test` script is a basic sleep loop just for testing...

```
#!/bin/bash
c=1
while [ "$c" -le 10 ]
do
        echo "sleep 10 seconds, c=$c"
        sleep 10s
        c=$((c+1))
        if [ "$c" -eq 10 ]
        then
                echo "max count reach, exit"
                exit
        fi
done
```

But what I found is the ssh keeps session alive (wait idle for 100 seconds), how can I drop the session?
The command I use is
`sshpass -p XXXX ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@IP 'bash -s' < localScript`

Comment: Replace `&` with `2>&1 &` or with `2>/dev/null &`.

Comment: Still not work .... :(

Comment: I believe when you invoke `ssh` to run a remote command without a PTY, the remote `sshd` process closes the session when it gets EOF on the PIPE that it creates for the remote process's standard output. In other words, you're getting this because the "test" script process, or the "bash -s" process, or some other process is still running with an open file descriptor to the "bash -s" process's stdout. Maybe your shell startup files (.bashrc etc) are starting some other command in the background besides what's in the script?

Comment: I could not figure out the preferable solution, so what I use is `timeout seconds ssh ...`

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you force pseudo-terminal allocation (-t):

```
sshpass -p XXXX ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@IP 'bash -s' < localScript
```